# In flutter I am facing range Error (Index) issue. I wants to display data for 1-9 range i.e from acts[0] to acts[8]

Tags: flutter, api, dart

As my flutter application at initial stage it doesn't have enough data that's why API responding data for [0]th and [1]th location only.On the screen I wants to show data for 1-9 range location.Now problem is that how to show another data like "N/A" if there is no data at that location.Below is my code:
For acts[0] and acts[1] API is returning response so there is no issue for that but for acts[3] there is no data coming from API so its throwing an error: RangeError(index):index out of range:index should be less than 3:3

```
import 'package:AtDocHUB/Controller/ActivityController.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/Controller/DocumentController.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/Model/Activity.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/Model/ActivityCount.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/Model/Document.dart';
    
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/Notification/NotificationPage.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/AppointmentPageFE.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/Activity/ActivityStatusPage.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/Document/DocumentPage.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/Document/document_status_report.dart';
    import 'package:AtDocHUB/View/LoginPage.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_typeahead/flutter_typeahead.dart';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    
    class homePageAdmin extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<homePageAdmin> createState() => _homePageAdminState();
    }
    
    class _homePageAdminState extends State<homePageAdmin> {
      List<Activity> activity = [];
      List<ActivityCount> acts = [];
    
      ActivityController activityController = Get.put(ActivityController());
    
      late Future<ActivityCount> futureActivity;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        init();
      }
    
      Future init() async {
        final acts = await ActivityController.userDashboard();
        setState(() => this.acts = acts);
      }
    
      void getDocID() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= acts.length; i++) {}
      }
    
      final TextEditingController typeaheadTitle = TextEditingController();
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    
      @override
      late final int docId;
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Widget NotifyIt()=> NotificationPage();
    
        return Scaffold(
            key: scaffoldKey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
              title: Text('AtDocHub'),
              leading: IconButton(
                  icon: BackButtonIcon(),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()))),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 87, 156),
                  ),
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    homePageAdmin()));
                          }
                          //}
                          //  }
                          //},
                          ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.file_copy_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      DocumentPage()),
                              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.schedule,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      AppointmentPageFE()),
                              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.local_activity,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      ActivityStatusPage()),
                              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
              FittedBox(
                child: Row(children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.person),
                        Text(
                          'Admin / Support',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 190,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      AdminNotification()));
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.notifications,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            // style: TextStyle(
                            //     fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                    // width: 10,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    child: TypeAheadField<Document>(
                      hideSuggestionsOnKeyboardHide: true,
                      textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              typeaheadTitle.clear();
                              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                            },
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Document Title or Token No ',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        controller: this.typeaheadTitle,
                      ),
                      suggestionsCallback: DocumentController.getdocs,
                      itemBuilder: (context, Document suggestion) {
                        final user = suggestion;
    
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(user.docTitle),
                        );
                      },
                      noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => Container(
                        height: 100,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'No Documents Found.',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onSuggestionSelected: (Document? suggestion) {
                        final user = suggestion!;
                        this.typeaheadTitle.text = user.docTitle;
    
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                DocumentStatusReport(user.docId)));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Draft Sent Pending ',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 40,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 0 &&
                                              (acts[0].activityId % 100 == 1))
                                          ? '${acts[0].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
    
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    // Text('${acts[0].count}'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(child: Text('Draft Approval Pending')),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 40,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 1 &&
                                              (acts[1].activityId % 100 == 2))
                                          ? '${acts[1].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child:
                                            Text('Appointment Schedule Pending')),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 40,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 2 &&
                                              (acts[2].activityId % 100 == 3))
                                          ? '${acts[2].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child:
                                            Text('Appointment Execution Pending')),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 40,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 3 &&
                                              (acts[3].activityId % 100 == 4))
                                          ? '${acts[3].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                              elevation: 3,
                              child: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Text('Charges Collection Pending')),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 40,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 4 &&
                                              (acts[4].activityId % 100 == 5))
                                          ? '${acts[4].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            child: Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Text('Challan Submission Pending')),
                                    Row(
                                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 40,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          (acts.length > 5 &&
                                                  (acts[5].activityId % 100 == 6))
                                              ? '${acts[5].count}'
                                              : 'N/A',
                                        ),
    
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 5,
                                        ),
                                        // Text(
                                        //   '${acts[6].count}',
                                        // ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            child: Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Text('Document Submission Pending')),
                                    Row(
                                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 40,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          (acts.length > 6 &&
                                                  (acts[6].activityId % 100 == 7))
                                              ? '${acts[6].count}'
                                              : 'N/A',
                                        ),
    
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 5,
                                        ),
                                        // Text(
                                        //   '${acts[6].count}',
                                        // ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            child: Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child:
                                            Text('Document Registration Pending')),
                                    Row(
                                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 40,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          (acts.length > 7 &&
                                                  (acts[7].activityId % 100 == 8))
                                              ? '${acts[7].count}'
                                              : 'N/A',
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 5,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Card(
                            elevation: 3,
                            child: Container(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 246, 252),
                              child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(child: Text('Document Sent Pending')),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 168,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      (acts.length > 8 &&
                                              (acts[8].activityId % 100 == 9))
                                          ? '${acts[8].count}'
                                          : 'N/A',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
            ])));
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is `acts` data? actually?

Comment: `(acts.isEmpty) ? '${acts[3].count}' : 'N/A',`  i think its typo, should be `itNotEmpty`

Comment: acts is whole array @pmatatias

Answer (score 1):

First change your `userDashboard()` to this:

```
static Future<List<ActivityCount?>> userDashboard() async {//<--- add this
    final url = Uri.parse('13.233.206.251:8088/…');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      var list = parsed
          .map<ActivityCount>((json) => ActivityCount.fromJson(json))
          .toList();

      List<ActivityCount?> result = []; //<--- add these
      for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (list[i] != null && list[i].activityId % 100 == i + 1) {
          result.add(list[i]);
        } else {
          result.add(null);
        }
      }
      return result;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Document');
    }
  }
```

then change this :

```
Text(
  (acts.isEmpty) ? '${acts[3].count}' : 'N/A',
),
```

to this:

```
Text(
  (acts[3] == null && (acts[3].actID % 100 != 4)) ? 'N/A':'${acts[3].count}',
),
```

do this for all 9 row, just remember this is the pattern :

```
Text(
  (acts[index] == null  && (acts[index].actID % 100 != index + 1)) ? 'N/A' : '${acts[index].count}',
),
```

Comment: `acts.isEmpty` is not required if you check `acts.length > 3` anyway. Everytime your second condition is true (acts.length > x) your first condition (acts.isNotEmpty) is also true. So you can shorten it to `Text(acts.length > 3 ? '${acts[3].count}' : 'N/A');`

Comment: @eamirho3ein  still there is issue I wants to show data for particular activity ID. For all 9 activities I wants to show data corresponding to that particular activity ID only so, even if we are checking length we still need to know activity ID then we have to show data for that ID. API returning response like this:  [{"activityId":101,"count":1},{"activityId":102,"count":1},{"activityId":109,"count":2}]  for activity ID 101 i have show count of it in front of text in 1st row for actID 102 have to show it on 2nd row and for actID109 i have to show it in front of text of 9th row

Comment: I didn't get this part ` have to show it in front of text of 9th row`, your list only contain 3 item. you don't have 9 row. you only have 3 row.

Comment: @eamirho3ein no there are total 9 row for which I wants to show its count corresponding to its actID in front of each text for 1 -9 row

Comment: ooo now I get it. do you have any class model ? if yes could you include that and the code where you are using it ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I have updated question and posted my whole code

Comment: @MinalSuryawanshi did you try my last update?

Comment: Yes I tried it but, showing "N/A" for last one "Document sent pending" but API response is [{"activityId":101,"count":1},{"activityId":102,"count":1},{"activityId":109,"count":2}]  so it should show 2 for last one @eamirho3ein

Comment: @MinalSuryawanshi could you update your question with my answer? so I see where is you problem is?

Comment: could you also add the part you pars the api response?and also your ActivityCount class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248753/discussion-between-minal-suryawanshi-and-eamirho3ein).

Comment: @eamirho3ein updated code in question also sent you api response code and Activity class in chats

Comment: @MinalSuryawanshi I updated my answer, did you get what you need?